# Haproxy 1.5.3 / OpenSSL - Creating PEM

Tags: haproxy, openssl

I have an HAProxy Server set up with the line:

`bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.pem`

I have the following files:

`/etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.key`

`/etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.csr`

I have purchased a certificate from Geotrust which gives me a `Primary Intermediate Certificate`, `Secondary Intermediate Certificate` and `End Entity Certificate`

I have concatenated the files, in PIC, SID, EEC, KEY order in to `/etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.pem` which passes `openssl verify /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.pem` and `openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.pem /etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.pem`

I have also verified this file using http://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

When I run `haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c` I get

`'bind *:443 : inconsistencies between private key and certificate loaded from PEM file '/etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.pem'`

`Proxy 'http-in': no SSL certificate specified for bind '*:443' at [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg] (use 'crt')`

I am new to SSL Certificates and I'm stuck where to go. Googling for answers has had me run a merry mile and I'm no further forward.

Have I done something wrong in creating the .pem file this way and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I wasn't getting the "inconsistencies between private key and certificate" error/warning, but I did get the "no SSL certificate specified". Using the answer you provided still fixed the issue for me :)

Answer (score 13):

Resolved.

I needed to create the PEM in order KEY, EEC, SID, PID instead of PID, SID, EEC, KEY

Comment: I've been struggling with this for the past ten hours, and this was the issue all along!

Comment: (I've always used the order: certificate, intermediate, intermediate, key, and that also works fine)